# I need to write a script that restarts a service periodically

Tags: windows, batch-file, jobs

I need to write a script that restarts a service periodically.  I guess it would be a job that keeps track of the Established connections to a specific port on a server.  Once a certain number of connections is reached it will restart the services.

Here is what I have so far:

```
netstat -an | find /c ":80" //To find the count

net stop "Service Name" //To stop the service

net start "Service Name" //To start the service
```

Comment: You can use for example [Window's task scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7).